Relativity and wave (function) “squeezing”
Seem like nature have max speed limit so to conserve energy/momentum some of the speed increase goes into increasing wave frequency which is kind of “squeezing” the wave.
For example, light-wave fired by moving observer will have higher frequency when measured by relatively standing observer.
Does it also hold for particles with mass like electron? Will the standing observer see some of its speed transferred into “squeezing” its wave function (frequency increase)?
For example, 0.8c moving observer fires electron in 0.8c so standing observer will see the electron in 0.97c and not 1.6c.
Will, just like in the light case, some of the momentum go to the wave function and the observer will notice all the diff with increased wave frequency?

Since $p=h/\lambda$, where $h$ is Planck's constant, $p$ is momentum of a particle and $\lambda$ is the wavelength of the wavefunction for that particle, then yes a faster moving electron (higher $p$) will have a smaller wavelength. A smaller wavelength corresponds to a higher frequency, which can be seen by combining the relativistic energy-momentum relationship $E^2=p^2c^2 + m^2c^4$ with the quantum equation relating energy and frequency, $E=h f$ (where $E$ is energy, $m$ is rest mass, $c$ is the speed of light, $f$ is frequency) to yield the dispersion relationship $f^2 = c^2/\lambda^2 + m^2 c^4 / h^2$.
So, I agree that a swiftly moving electron will appear to an observer to have a higher frequency, compared to a slowly moving or stationary electron. This is indeed analogous to the Doppler effect.
I have a quibble with your language, though. I would not say "some of the momentum go to the wave function." To me, that sounds like the overall momentum is split into several contributions, and one of those contributions is responsible for changing the frequency of the wavefunction, while other contributions have other effects. What is really going on is simpler; the frequency of the wavefunction is directly related to the momentum of the particle, through the dispersion relationship described above.

But the standing observer (in my 0.8c example) also notice a relativistic speed increase which is part of the momentum along with the wave-frequency, no?
Electron can have higher frequency (higher energy) without speed increase, no (wave)? Or can electron speed be deduced just by its wave-frequency?

E=hf is not just for photons?

@RaniSharoni Correct: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matter_wave. The relationship between energy and frequency, and momentum and wavelength, is the same for both. In this context, the main difference between photons and electrons is that photons are massless, so the relationship between energy anad momentum (or frequency and wavelength) is different. For photons $E=pc$, whereas for electrons $E^2=p^2c^2 + m^2c^4$, which means the dispersion relationship for photons is $f = c/\lambda$, whereas for electrons it is $f^2=c^2/\lambda^2 + m^2c^4/h^2$.

You can solve $p=\gamma m v$ where $\gamma=(1-v^2/c^2)^{1/2}$ for the speed $v$ of the electron in terms of the momentum, and then relate it to $E, f, \lambda$ if you want to.

The wiki “wave matter” page you mentioned shows wavelength/frequence as function of the velocity. As a conclusion: “This shows that as the velocity of a particle approaches zero (rest) the de Broglie wavelength approaches infinity.”
What is the meaning of infinite wavelength (while frequence is non-zero)? Does it imply that particle can never be at rest?
Functions – λ=h/(γmv) f=γmc^2/h

@RaniSharoni The short answer is that there is no problem with a particle being at rest. If you want a physical picture, you can just picture a really big wavelength. The rigorous answer involves rigged Hilbert spaces and requires a real understanding of quantum mechanics.
